firestore issue cant save data in firestore database
the the account created correctly with Firebase auth but i have a issue with fire store i think it the function cause I am getting this error : firebaseconfig.firestoreDB.collection is not a function(it is undefined).
when i ask chat GPT, it keep give me the same thing and it is not helping anymore
// this is firebaseconfig.js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "",
appId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firestore after initializing Firebase
const firestoreDB = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

// Export Firebase Auth and Firestore instances
export const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
export { firestoreDB };

//this the register.js

import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { firebaseAuth } from '../database/firebaseconfig';
import { firestoreDB } from '../database/firebaseconfig';

const Register = () => {
const navigation = useNavigation();
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');


const handleRegister = () => {

if (!email || !password) {
  Alert.alert('Error', 'Please fill in all fields');
  return;
}
if (password !== confirmPassword) {
  Alert.alert('Error', 'Passwords do not match');
  return;
}


createUserWithEmailAndPassword(firebaseAuth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    
    const user = userCredential.user;
    Alert.alert('Success', 'Account created successfully!');

   
    firestoreDB.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
      username: username,
      email: email,
     
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('User information saved to Firestore');
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error saving user information to Firestore: ', error);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
  });
};

can someone help
help im strugling with this i want to save those info in firestore  and i not know what to do

I think you're mixing Firebase JS SDK Modular API and Web namespaced API implementation. The correct way to write data to Firestore Database is the following:
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document in collection "cities"
await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
  name: "Los Angeles",
  state: "CA",
  country: "USA"
});

See this documentation for your reference.
